# How to select an sql index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to select an sql index

I have an table TabEmp with fields `c_ID (primary key)`, and `c_Emp_ID`.

I created an index on it `idx_TabEmp (non-clustered)` with the fields `c_ID (primary key)` and `c_Emp_ID`

I am using select statement

```
select * from index = idx_TabEmp
```

It throws an error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'index'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax
```

I am using

```
select * from TabEmp (index = idx_TabEmp)
```

it works, but I am not sure if that is the correct way to select an index

Can you please tell me the correct way to query an index?

Comment: The optimiser should use the index automatically if it will benefit the query. Look at the Execution Plan to determine what index is being used.

Comment: In SQL Server, you don't need to / don't typically specify what index to use - SQL Server's query optimizer will figure that out automatically. Just do your `SELECT (list of columns) FROM (tablename)` and if the index helps, SQL Server will use it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the syntax for a table hint.

```
SELECT column_list FROM table_name WITH (INDEX (index_name) [, ...]);
```

in sql server which I think is your case based on your error.

As to whether the index will be picked up or not (both in oracle and sql server) will depend on a lot of other reasons. As the name indicates, it is just a **hint** to the optimizer. The cost of the query using the hint and without the hint will eventually be the deciding factors for the optimizer.

**In most cases, you'll not see the need to specify the hint.** The optimizer used this access path if using the index is the best way to retrieve the data and all the meta data (statistics) indicate the same.

Comment: AFAIK it will always respect the hint even if it leads to a ridiculous plan. e.g. in AdventureWorks try `SELECT BirthDate FROM HumanResources.Employee WITH (INDEX(IX_Employee_OrganizationLevel_OrganizationNode) ) WHERE SickLeaveHours = 1` The NCI doesn't contain either `BirthDate` or `SickLeaveHours` but still gets used.

Comment: I used "SELECT *  FROM table_name WITH (INDEX (index_name))"
and was working faster than 
"SELECT *  FROM table_name ".

Comment: But I am not sure how to give HINT permissions in the SQL administrator.

Answer (score 9):

The index is something which the optimizer picks up "automagically - ideally you don't need to force select an index.

If you really want to force select the index, use index hint

```
SELECT *
FROM TabEmp
WITH (INDEX(idx_TabEmp))
```

---

Also, note that with no filter conditions (ie, no `WHERE` clauses), the Index does not come into the picture since you are not searching for a specific data - you're selecting everything.

To provide the book analogy - when you're reading a full book cover to cover - you don't need to look at the Index. It's only when you're searching for a specific page that you look at the index and find what you want.

Comment: The OP is on SQL Server (see the error message in the question)